# AttributeError on <module '__main__' when deploying app on Heroku via Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, heroku, scikit-learn, attributeerror

I am new to Django/Heroku but am trying to launch my first project with these tools that includes a pre-trained SK model and custom Pipelines. I've got everything working fine locally but when I try to push to Heroku I keep receiving 500 errors and my log tail is posted below. I can't seem to solve it.

My custom transformer pipeline that I wrote has a class called FeatureSelector as well as CategoricalTransformer, which I've pasted into the manage.py file (as someone suggested doing that, and I didn't know where else they might go). Heroku, or gunicorn, or something seems to have issues with this.

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FeatureSelector' on <module '__main__' from '/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn'>
```

I've tried renaming the apps.py file, putting the pipeline in WSGI, moving the joblibs etc. but nothing seems to work for me.

Thanks to anyone who's able to help out. Also I've posted the entire log file at the very bottom for anyone who needs it.

File structure:

```
project
       --app
           -- ml_models
              -- model.joblib
              -- transformer.joblib
           -- apps.py
           -- views.py
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
import os
from joblib import load
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

class PredictorConfig(AppConfig):
    # create path to models
    predictor_path = os.path.join(settings.MODELS, 'model.joblib')
    transformer_path = os.path.join(settings.MODELS,'transformer.joblib')

    # load models into separate variables
    # these will be accessible via this class
    predictor = load(predictor_path)
    pipeline = load(transformer_path)
```

views.py

```
...
from .apps import PredictorConfig

    ...

    prediction = PredictorConfig.predict(data)
    ...
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn diamonds.wsgi --log-file -
```

wsgi.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'diamonds.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and finally settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_filters',
]
```

Entire heroku log

```
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092509+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-23 18:13:28 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Error handling request /
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092549+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092552+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092553+00:00 app[web.1]: self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092553+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092554+00:00 app[web.1]: respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092554+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092554+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.get_response(request)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092555+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092556+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092556+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092556+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092557+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 103, in response_for_exception
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092558+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092559+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 141, in handle_uncaught_exception
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092559+00:00 app[web.1]: callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092559+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 602, in resolve_error_handler
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092560+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092560+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092560+00:00 app[web.1]: res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092561+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092561+00:00 app[web.1]: return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092562+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/diamonds/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092565+00:00 app[web.1]: from detail_page.views import detail_view
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/detail_page/views.py", line 4, in <module>
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092565+00:00 app[web.1]: from .apps import PredictorConfig
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/detail_page/apps.py", line 9, in <module>
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092566+00:00 app[web.1]: class PredictorConfig(AppConfig):
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092566+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/detail_page/apps.py", line 18, in PredictorConfig
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092566+00:00 app[web.1]: pipeline = load(transformer_path)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092567+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092567+00:00 app[web.1]: obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092567+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092568+00:00 app[web.1]: obj = unpickler.load()
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092568+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092568+00:00 app[web.1]: dispatch[key[0]](self)
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092569+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1385, in load_stack_global
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092569+00:00 app[web.1]: self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092569+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1428, in find_class
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092570+00:00 app[web.1]: return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092570+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 299, in _getattribute
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092570+00:00 app[web.1]: .format(name, obj)) from None
2021-03-23T18:13:28.092571+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FeatureSelector' on <module '__main__' from '/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn'>
2021-03-23T18:13:28.093025+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.79.236.200 - - [23/Mar/2021:18:13:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688831+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-23 18:13:30 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Error handling request /favicon.ico
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688874+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688876+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688877+00:00 app[web.1]: self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688877+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688877+00:00 app[web.1]: respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688878+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688878+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.get_response(request)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688879+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688880+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688880+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688881+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688881+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 103, in response_for_exception
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688882+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688883+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 141, in handle_uncaught_exception
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688883+00:00 app[web.1]: callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688884+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 602, in resolve_error_handler
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688885+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688885+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688886+00:00 app[web.1]: res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688886+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688887+00:00 app[web.1]: return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688887+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688887+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688888+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688888+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688889+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688889+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688890+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688890+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688890+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/diamonds/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688891+00:00 app[web.1]: from detail_page.views import detail_view
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688891+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/detail_page/views.py", line 4, in <module>
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688891+00:00 app[web.1]: from .apps import PredictorConfig
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688892+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/detail_page/apps.py", line 9, in <module>
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688892+00:00 app[web.1]: class PredictorConfig(AppConfig):
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688892+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/detail_page/apps.py", line 18, in PredictorConfig
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688893+00:00 app[web.1]: pipeline = load(transformer_path)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688893+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688894+00:00 app[web.1]: obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688894+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688895+00:00 app[web.1]: obj = unpickler.load()
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688895+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688896+00:00 app[web.1]: dispatch[key[0]](self)
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688896+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1385, in load_stack_global
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688896+00:00 app[web.1]: self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688897+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1428, in find_class
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688897+00:00 app[web.1]: return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688897+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 299, in _getattribute
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688898+00:00 app[web.1]: .format(name, obj)) from None
2021-03-23T18:13:30.688898+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FeatureSelector' on <module '__main__' from '/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn'>
```

Comment: In your file structure the root directory is called `app` but in your Procfile it's `diamonds` - is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your project correctly first? This is how:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration
Also, putting more of the error or other info into the question would be helpful.